# connect two tables in mysql giving duplicate results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to connect 2 tables in `mysql`. But, I am getting duplicate values. This [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca15e/3) will clear what I meant to say.

In result, you can see the `TW_ID` and `PFC_ID`. I just need `(1, 1), (11, 11), (21, 21)` and so on.. Right now I am getting `(1, 1), (1, 11), (1, 21), ...`

I am using this query:

```
SELECT tw.id as tw_id, pfc.id as pfc_id
FROM account_treasury_wholesale tw
INNER JOIN purchase_foreign_currency pfc
    ON tw.wholesaler_id = pfc.currency_supplier_id
WHERE tw.wholesaler_id='11'
```

Let me know, if you need more clarification. Thanks.

Comment: I tried both of them

Comment: Why GROUP BY? (Are there any aggregate functions to be used?)

Comment: A join is a cross product (usually with conditions.) If one t1 row matches 4 t2 rows, you'll get 1 x 4 = 4 rows back. If 2 t1 rows matches 4 t2 rows, you get 2 x 4 = 8 rows back. If you want any other logic you have to describe it better - in words or in SQL.

Comment: Your sql fiddle shows that your first table contains four rows matching the WHERE condition in your query. It also shows that you have seven rows matching in your second column.  Finally, the same column that's mentioned in the WHERE clause is mentioned in the ON clause of your JOIN.

So, your result set contains seven x four = 28 rows. I can't tell from your question what you actually want. I could try to guess, but both datasets are full of the value '11' so it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Either you JOIN `ON tw.id=pfc.id`, or if that's not applicable you may need to revise your schema.

This is what happens when you JOIN `ON tw.wholesaler_id = pfc.currency_supplier_id`:

1. The first row retrieved from the `tw` table is `tw.id=1` (because of your `WHERE` clause)
2. That row's `tw.wholesaler_id` is 11, so it will look for rows in the `pfc` table for those with `pfc.currency_supplier_id` also equal to 11 -- which is 4 rows (`id` equal to 1, 11, 21, 23). So the cross product will be `(1, 1)`, `(1, 11)`, `(1,21)`, `(1,23)`
3. The next row from the `tw` table is retrieved and the same search happens with the `pfc` table, which will lead to `(11,1), (11,11), (11,21), (11,23)`...

I admit I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. A little more explanation might help.